# Does Rig Veda 10.59.7 talk about rebirth?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, rebirth

[Rig Veda 10.59.7](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10059.htm)

> May Earth restore to us our vital spirit, may Heaven the Goddess and
>   mid-air restore it. **May Soma give us once again our body**, and Pūṣan
>   show the Path of peace and comfort.

What is the context of this verse? And does this talk about rebirth?

Answer (score 3):

Please review the following hindi translation of the same verse [Rig Veda 10.59.7](http://literature.awgp.org/book/rigveda/v9.75):

[image]

Which basically translates differently to what you posted, it says:

> Earth, space and mid-air again provides us the vital energy (prana), somdev again
>   provides us the physical ability and pushadev that feeds everything
>   provides us compassionate voice, so that we are blessed in every way.

So, it doesn't talk anything about rebirth.

Comment: Which word here is translating to physical ability? What could be the reason for difference of choices?

Comment: The 2nd word in sanskrit in the 2nd line.